# Cookie is getting reset on AJAX requests

Tags: asp.net, ajax, cookies

I have two virtual directories, one hosts an application the other hosts a web service layer running WCF with ASP.NET compatibility mode enabled.

The service project has an HTTP module that deals with authentication for incoming requests. The login service writes an authentication cookie to the client.

Subsequent requests are handled via AJAX (jQuery) to the services from the application project (another virtual directory on the same domain.)

Cookie domain is set correctly, the cookie path is "/", the cookie is set to HTTP ONLY so that scripts cannot interact with it.

My issue is the login service seems to be sending the SET-COOKIE header with the correct payload in the cookie, however the subsequent requests are not sending the cookie back to the server, in fact when inspecting the local store the cookie is not even there.

Potentially what could be my issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tracked the issue down to Chrome. Apparently there was a prior bug that seems to be presenting itself again whereby expires cookies are not promoted to session and are instead discarded.